# print category name for a particular post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to print a category name of a post as class name and a output like this

```
<figure class="testimonial-thumb gallery-item **some_category_name** ">
```

and when I am using the code like

```
<figure class="testimonial-thumb gallery-item <?php echo the_category(','); ?> ">
```

But it is breaking the tag printing on browser.Please suggest some solution.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: What is the output of just `echo the_category(',');`? Do you have quote amrks or <> in your category names?

Comment: `echo the_category(' ');` will do (you cannot separate css classes with commas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot separate css classes with comma. Use spaces. Try something like:

```
  <figure 
    class="testimonial-thumb gallery-item <?php 
      echo the_category(' '); 
    ?>"
  >
```

Check out: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category examples section for a very similar example of this kind.

Comment: Thank you elcodedocle... i am not getting the category name in browser, how should i mention $id value?

Comment: i am getting values like idea "> in browser

Comment: it is printing "Array" instead

Comment: hey thanks a lot Colin and elcodedocle for ur assistance.. 
actually i tried this and it worked..

<?php global $post; $category = get_the_category($post->ID); echo $category[0]->name; ?>

Comment: Your're welcomed :-) The code I've posted should get you the category names of the current post, separated by spaces, inside the figure tag class attribute. I've edited my answer to use `the_category`, but you can use `get_the_category` too (as I was doing on previous edits) and loop through the array of post categories, getting the id of each one, the name, or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the entity

`&gt;`

Which will display as >

Comment: i was going to do that, but using some spaces bought it properly.. Thank you :)